# Result different in Powershell.exe compared to Powershell IDE

Tags: powershell, ide, difference

Any idea why this is happening? I'm trying to build a string that contains all the information I want (the final is to be output in a GUI, in a DataGridView cell), in Powershell.exe the mediatype and healthstatus are shown as codes (3,4,0) instead of the strings (HDD,SSD,OK) like shown in IDE:

The code is exactly the same in both :

```
$DisquesPhysiques = invoke-command -ComputerName XXXX -ScriptBlock {get-physicaldisk}

foreach ($disque in $DisquesPhysiques) {
$infodisque = $($disque.FriendlyName) + " - " + $($disque.SerialNumber)+ " - "  + $($disque.MediaType)+ " - "  + $($disque.HealthStatus)+ " - "  + $([math]::Round($disque.Size/1gb))  + " GB"
$infodisque
}
```

[image]

The WEIRDEST part is sometimes it will not show codes and it will show actual words (SDD, HDD, Healthy). This is very problematic since I can't rely on it being a number or a word consistently!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was very strange so I ended up getting the info from CIM (WMI) and do an IF on the media type (4 is SDD):

```
$DisquesPhysiques = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $poste MSFT_PhysicalDisk -Namespace Root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage

                foreach ($disque in $DisquesPhysiques)
                {
                    if ($disque.MediaType -eq 4) { $type = "SSD" }
                    else { $type = "HDD" }
                    $infodisque = $($disque.FriendlyName) + " - " + $($disque.SerialNumber) + " - " + $type + " - " + $([math]::Round($disque.Size/1gb)) + " GB"
                    $tableInfoPoste.Rows.add("Disque physique", $infodisque)
                }
```